# Arduino SIM5320e HTTP GET request to 000webhost.com

Tags: http, iot

Im having trouble getting a successful HTTP GET request to a domain under [000webhost.com](http://000webhost.com)

I am trying to do a GET request which sends data to a php file on my domain and save it to MySQL database. I also did this first on my browser and it works fine so I don't think there are problem in my php file.

**MY DOMAIN:** ***wastedb.000webhostapp.com***

But if I try to send a request to [dweet.io](http://dweet.io), it works as expected.

I am using a modified version of Adafruit_FONA library and will post the code snippet and response from serial monitor below.

Here are the parameters that I used for the ***WORKING*** GET request:

**Host Address:** *www.dweet.io*

**Host:** *dweet.io*

**Response from Serial monitor for dweet.io (working):**

```
---> AT+CHTTPSSTART
<--- OK
---> AT+CHTTPSOPSE="www.dweet.io",80,1
<--- OK
---> AT+CHTTPSSEND=64
<--- >
---> GET /dweet/for/gearhead?hello=world HTTP/1.1
Host: dweet.io


<--- OK
---> AT+CHTTPSSEND
<--- OK
<--- +CHTTPSSEND: 0
---> AT+CHTTPSRECV?
<--- +CHTTPSRECV: LEN,361
---> AT+CHTTPSRECV=361
<--- OK
+CHTTPSRECV: DATA,361
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Wed, 30 Jan 2019 00:16:43 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 196

{"this":"succeeded","by":"dweeting","the":"dweet","with":{"thing
---> AT+CHTTPSCLSE
<--- OK
---> AT+CHTTPSSTOP
<--- OK
```

As we can see, the Arduino received a JSON response from the website.

Here are the parameters that I used for the ***NOT WORKING*** GET request:

**Host Address:** *wastedb.000webhostapp.com*

**Host:** *wastedb.000webhostapp.com*

**Response from Serial monitor for wastedb.000webhostapp.com (NOT WORKING):**

```
---> AT+CHTTPSSTART
<--- OK
---> AT+CHTTPSOPSE="wastedb.000webhostapp.com",80,1
<--- OK
---> AT+CHTTPSSEND=113
<--- >
---> GET /wastedb/get_location.php?lat=14.640155&lon=120.974920&stat=LOW HTTP/1.1
Host: wastedb.000webhostapp.com


<--- OK
---> AT+CHTTPSSEND
<--- ERROR
```

Am I missing something here? Seems like the shield cannot find the Host Server I provided for my website.

***EDIT:*** It is working now. The only solution that worked for me is to find another [hosting site](https://hostbuddy.com).

Comment: Please consider answering your own question with the information in your "edit". After a day or two, you can accept your answer as the solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is working now. The only solution that worked for me is to find another hosting site.

Answer (score 4):

Try just using IP address for the Host line instead. I did the same thing for POST and it works fine for me.

Example:

Host: 13.xxx.xx.xx

[image: sucessful POST]